# Центральное положение окна консоли - Как реализовать?

Tags: c#, консоль

Попробовал такой метод: ( но при запуске он не сразу появляется в центре,а с задержкой)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd,int hWndInsertAfter, 
                               int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

public const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
public static IntPtr MyConsole = GetConsoleWindow();

public static void Inizialize()
{
  var xpos = 450;
  var ypos = 350;
  SetWindowPos(MyConsole, 0, xpos, ypos, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
}
```

Можно ли вызвать консоль в центральной(`CenterScreen`) области сразу при запуске, без задержки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена данным способом, при запуске окно мгновенно появляется в центре экрана рабочего стола.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos
(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    int hWndInsertAfter, 
    int x, 
    int Y, 
    int cx, 
    int cy, 
    int wFlags
);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

public static void Inizialize()
{
   var wndRect = new RECT();
   var cWidth = wndRect.Right - wndRect.Left;
   var cHeight = wndRect.Bottom - wndRect.Top;
   var SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
   var HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
   var Width = 1366;
   var Height = 768;
   IntPtr handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
   SetWindowPos
   (
       handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 
       Width / 3 - cWidth / 2, Height / 2 - cHeight / 2, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE
   );
}
```

P.S: За место `GetConsoleWindow` решил взять `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle`,подумал что так будет проще)